# How to evaluate Google News traffic in Google Analytics

Tags: seo, google-analytics, google-search-console

One of my sites has recently been included in Google News and I am seeing a spike in traffic. However, when I try to analyze the source of the traffic via referrals, Google News traffic number is tiny (news.google).

I am seeing increases in both organic and direct traffic channels as well as my queries and impressions in GWT. I am working with a 3 week sample so this is not a random event. Increases are steady.

Could some of the Google News traffic be placed under organic or direct in my GA reports.

Comment: Congratulations!!

Comment: @closetnoc Thanks. Now I just need to keep the content flowing...

Comment: That is the part I hate... who needs content anyway? I think it is a Google conspiracy to enrich themselves on the backs of us lowly techno-dweebs. We may not be the 99%, but we are at least 9%. ;-) Call Jesse Ventura- I am sure he can tell us that the big G is evil!! I bet he can link it to MK-Ultra somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someone is coming from https://news.google.com/ you will see *news.google.com / referral* as a source / medium.

But when traffic is coming from https://www.google.com/?tbm=nws (google news in SERP) it's tagged as *google / organic*